# Stripping 's (apostrophe s) from a string

Tags: python, string

I would like to strip 's (apostrophe s) from a string.

For example:

```
a="it's tail was big".split()
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]= a[i].strip(r"\'s")
```

a becomes

```
['it', 'tail', 'wa', 'big']
```

whereas I am expecting

```
['it', 'tail', 'was', 'big']
```

How do I make it strip 's and not s ? I tried strip(r"\'s") too & it doesn't work either.

And

Is there a better way to do this than what I have done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace the `'s` with empty string and then split.

```
>>> txt ="it's tail was big"
>>> txt.replace("'s", '').split()
['it', 'tail', 'was', 'big']
```

Comment: Could be worth using: re.sub("'s? ", " ", txt).split()

Comment: @fileoffset, that works too. Any idea if using RegExp would be faster than string replace?

Comment: @RKB : ofocurse regex is faster than string replace()

Comment: I wouldn't say regex is definitely faster. It can be quite slow compared to a basic replace but what you sacrifice in speed you gain in flexibility. The regex I posted will also work for words like Chris' (where the trailing 's' is left off - this is valid English grammar).